# React native app with Hermes crashes with "SIGSEGV: Segmentation violation (invalid memory reference) "

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes

In our crash tracking app bugsnag, I see an increasing amount of crashes with "SIGSEGV: Segmentation violation (invalid memory reference)". They seem to happen only on Android and the stacktrace is full of libhermes.so.

This stacktraces tells me nothing and I haven't found any existing questions with the same problem. Does anyone have an idea where to look for the root cause for this? Is it a javascript error that hermes turns into a SIGSEGV? A bug in hermes? A crash in one of the libraries we use?

Stacktrace from one of the crashes.

````
SIGSEGV Segmentation violation (invalid memory reference) 
    /data/app/com.wolt.courierapp-poHmOlYLJ3-nWo0m_w4kVw==/lib/arm64/libhermes.so:116080 facebook::hermes::detail::hermesFatalErrorHandler(void*, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, bool)
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:1222852 0x701af048c4
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:1222588 0x701af047bc
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:1056428 0x701aedbeac
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:182328 0x701ae06838
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:523104 0x701ae59b60
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:298092 0x701ae22c6c
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:564832 0x701ae63e60
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:216036 0x701ae0ebe4
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:568480 0x701ae64ca0
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:578128 0x701ae67250
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:544160 0x701ae5eda0
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:539976 0x701ae5dd48
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:662544 0x701ae7bc10
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:723864 0x701ae8ab98
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:724172 0x701ae8accc
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:724136 0x701ae8aca8
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:645300 0x701ae778b4
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:543328 0x701ae5ea60
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:581332 0x701ae67ed4
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:544160 0x701ae5eda0
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:541776 0x701ae5e450
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:581364 0x701ae67ef4
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:544160 0x701ae5eda0
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:541776 0x701ae5e450
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:581364 0x701ae67ef4
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:544160 0x701ae5eda0
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:541776 0x701ae5e450
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:581364 0x701ae67ef4
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:544160 0x701ae5eda0
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:413044 0x701ae3ed74
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:543328 0x701ae5ea60
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:581332 0x701ae67ed4
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:544160 0x701ae5eda0
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:413044 0x701ae3ed74
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:543328 0x701ae5ea60
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:581332 0x701ae67ed4
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:544160 0x701ae5eda0
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:541776 0x701ae5e450
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:581364 0x701ae67ef4
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:544160 0x701ae5eda0
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:541776 0x701ae5e450
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:581364 0x701ae67ef4
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:544160 0x701ae5eda0
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:541776 0x701ae5e450
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes.so:147152 facebook::hermes::HermesRuntimeImpl::call(facebook::jsi::Function const&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes-executor-release.so:173936 facebook::jsi::Value facebook::jsi::Function::call<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, facebook::jsi::Value>(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, facebook::jsi::Value&&) const
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes-executor-release.so:173516 0x701a4765cc
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes-executor-release.so:154820 void std::__ndk1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void>::__call<void (*&)(std::__ndk1::function<void ()> const&, std::__ndk1::function<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > ()>), std::__ndk1::function<void ()> const&, std::__ndk1::function<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > ()> >(void (*&)(std::__ndk1::function<void ()> const&, std::__ndk1::function<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > ()>), std::__ndk1::function<void ()> const&, std::__ndk1::function<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > ()>&&)
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libhermes-executor-release.so:164992 facebook::react::JSIExecutor::callFunction(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, folly::dynamic const&)
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libreactnativejni.so:683496 0x701a639de8
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libreactnativejni.so:688656 0x701a63b210
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libreactnativejni.so:439588 0x701a5fe524
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libreactnativejni.so:372684 facebook::jni::detail::MethodWrapper<void (facebook::react::JNativeRunnable::*)(), &facebook::react::JNativeRunnable::run, facebook::react::JNativeRunnable, void>::dispatch(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<facebook::react::JNativeRunnable, facebook::react::Runnable>::JavaPart, facebook::react::Runnable, void>::_javaobject*>)
    /data/app/.../lib/arm64/libreactnativejni.so:372552 
    unknown 0x3850766e45494e4a```
````

Comment: When did that start to happen? After upgrading RN and enabled hermes? If that's the case, then maybe the upgrade process wasn't fully successful.

Answer (score 0):

Hermes is the a new JavaScript Engine for ReactNative you "can" use.

If you wan't to use it, you have to do some config-steps like described here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes

You can check in your *android/app/build.gradle* file, if Hermes is enabled within your App.
If yes, be aware, that hermes does not support "android-bundles", but only apk-Packages.

Maybe (I only guessing) you had still activate hermes some time ago, but now switch over from APK to Android-Bundles.

**BTW:** 
Did you use `logcat` to get your stacktrace? If not, please give it a try. It most of the time show error-messages you won't see in App-Stacktraces at the Device-Screen.

Comment: The thing is that this doesn't happen locally. If Hermes was broken completely, I would definitely know it. This issue happens many times every day, but the vast majority (99.x%) of Android users don't experience it.

Comment: Are you aware, that hermes doesn't work on sdk<=19. Do you have any logs about what kind of devices get this SIGSEGV? Are this older Android-Devices?

Comment: The issue with Hermes supporting Android App Bundles appears to have been resolved in SoLoader version 0.8.0 which was part of React-Native 0.61, see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26400#issuecomment-539395814

Answer (score 0):

please try adding the hermes configs, like thisin app/build.gradle

```js
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

     packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    } 
    
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.app"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk true  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
                        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
             signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "arm64-v8a":2, "x86":3, "x86_64": 4]
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 1000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "arm64-v8a":2, "x86":3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-share')
    implementation project(':react-native-view-shot')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-orientation')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-charts-wrapper')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
     implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_async-storage')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

and do npm install hermes-engine